# Upload an image, with other table entries, from HTML form while updating table with image information

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a HTML form which is taking two entries and an image. I'm trying to upload the image to a "target" folder and then put a hyperlink to the image in my SQL database for retrieval in future, whilst also adding my other 2 entries form the form. I've followed a number of tutorials and I still can't seem to get this to work. At the moment the mySQL is working for the date and entry. Nothing is being entered into the table for picture, nor is the picture being uploaded to the target.

HTML code

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mob_create.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td width="150">Date:</td></tr><tr>
            <td><input type="date" name="inputDate" value="" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Entry:</td></tr><tr>
            <td width="300"><input size="34" type="text" name="inputEntry" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150">Add an image (Optional):</td></tr><tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="inputPic" accept="image/*" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

PHP code

```
session_start();
include 'includes/Connect.php';

$target = "http://www.aam.prettypottery.ie/upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['inputPic']['name']);

$date = $_POST['inputDate'];
$entry = $_POST['inputEntry'];
$picture = ($_FILES['inputPic']['name']);
$username=$_SESSION['myusername'];

if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "Please complete all entries of the form";
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$username` (`Date`,`Entry`,`Picture`) VALUES('$date','$entry','$picture')") or die(mysql_error());
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure that they uploaded an image, and not a php shell for example :)

Comment: You have to use a local file system path for `move_uploaded_file` – not an HTTP URL, as you are currently doing. And go fix the SQL Injection vulnerability of your script ASAP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for the target needed to be local.

Also ensure that the folder in the target is writeable.

```
session_start();
include 'includes/Connect.php';

$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['inputPic']['name']);

$date = $_POST['inputDate'];
$entry = $_POST['inputEntry'];
$picture = ($_FILES['inputPic']['name']);
$username=$_SESSION['myusername'];

if(!$_POST['submit']) {
echo "Please complete all entries of the form";
} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$username` (`Date`,`Entry`,`Picture`) VALUES('$date','$entry','$picture')") or die(mysql_error());
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
} 
}
?>
```